# CheckedTextView using drawableleft showing 2 checkboxes

Tags: android, xml, layout, checkedtextview

I searched some and some guys said to use this

```
android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
```

I have the following layout code:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:drawableEnd="@null"
    android:drawableRight="@null"
    android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:drawableStart="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />
```

Doesnt change at all if i remove the lines

```
android:drawableEnd="@null"
android:drawableRight="@null"
```

I used this and got the following result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4KpE.png)

Edit: I am trying to make it appears in the left side...

Answer (score 0):

Remove all drawables (left, right, end, start...) from your layout. All you need for the check mark is the line you're already using:

```
 android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
```

Example of working CheckedTextView:

```
           <CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/isRideNeeded"
            style="@style/EditTemplateContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:checked="false"/>
```

Comment: This works, but, it shows the radio button at the right and i want it at the left, how can i do that? maybe i haven't explained me well, i'm trying to make it appears in the left side